# fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib' in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I am trying to write my first assembly language, "Hello World", but I keep on getting this error that says:

> fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'

Did I install the linker wrong or is there anything wrong with my code? here is my code

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none

include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc

includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib

.data

    HelloWorld db "Hello World!", 0

.code
start:

    invoke StdOut, addr HelloWorld
    invoke ExitProcess, 0

end start
```

Comment: The code is ok. It works like a charm here (WinXP). Try to reinstall MASM32 with the original installer from here: http://www.masm32.com/.

Comment: Try `includelib <c:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this in cmd in the `C:\masm32\bin` folder:

```
link /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /LIBPATH:c:\masm32\lib  file.obj
```

Answer (score 1):

im running masm32 on windows 10 and this code linked perfectly 
just needed to include some library

```
.486                         
.model flat, stdcall                   
option casemap :none                    

include \masm32\include\windows.inc     
include \masm32\macros\macros.asm       

include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
include \masm32\include\gdi32.inc
include \masm32\include\user32.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc

includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\gdi32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
```

.data

```
HelloWorld db "Hello World!", 0
```

.code
start:

```
invoke StdOut, addr HelloWorld
invoke ExitProcess, 0
```

end start

Answer (score 0):

try to save the project files in the same directory containing the assemler